# Can't initialize RMConnectCenter of RenRen SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.2

I tried to make Renren iOS app along with SocialPlugin docs.

http://wiki.mobile.renren.com/en/index.php/Social_Plugin_Download

I made AppDelegate belows. But every time I invoke app,  it failed
 at the point of RMConnectCenter initializeConnectWithAPIKey.

The Code is like this.

--noriakiAppDelegate.h--

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RMConnectCenter.h"

@class noriakiViewController;


@interface noriakiAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,RenrenMobileDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) noriakiViewController *noriakiviewcontroller;


@end
```

--noriakiAppDelegate.h.m--

```
#import "noriakiAppDelegate.h"
#import "noriakiViewController.h"


@implementation noriakiAppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize noriakiviewcontroller = _noriakiviewcontroller;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [RMConnectCenter initializeConnectWithAPIKey:@"MY API KEY" secretKey:@"MY SECRET" appId:@"2080970" mobileDelegate:self];


    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean application crashes when you call initializeConnectWithAPIKey ?

You are not passing your API Key and secret

```
[RMConnectCenter initializeConnectWithAPIKey:@"MY API KEY" secretKey:@"MY SECRET" appId:@"2080970" mobileDelegate:self];
```

Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Actually, I passed both 2 keys by replacing real keys. The code above is alternative fake string.
Also I'm using storyboard.